# CSS Pseudo element syntax

Tags: css

This is a vanity question, you've been warned!

I've never been a fan of partial definitions such as

```
.FlexAround1 {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-around;
    align-items:center;
} 

.FlexAround1::before {
    content:"";
}

.FlexAround1::after {
    content:"";
}
```

Today, I was like "but what if!?!?" and tried this:

```
.FlexAround1 {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-around;
    align-items:center;
} ::before {
    content:"";
} ::after {
    content:"";
}
```

and whaddayaknow, it actually works. Thing is though, I've never seen it written like that in any of the tutorials or reference sites. Is that proper CSS syntax or some kind of unofficial but somehow supported feature?

Comment: Your syntax is valid, but I doubt it's doing what you intend for it to do. It's three separate rules with the two last ones being applied to all elements, not just .Flexaround1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)

> A CSS pseudo-class is a keyword added to selectors that specifies a special state of the element to be selected.

A pseudo class is a keyword **added** to selectors. MDN goes on to give the syntax, defining it as

```
selector:pseudo-class {
  property: value;
}
```

So it appears that leaving out the selector isn't valid CSS (and kind of defeats the idea of a pseudo class in the first place anyways). Leaving out the selector appears to still work, however, the selector just defaults to `*`, applying your pseudo class to all elements.